# Get Series point value when plotting custom markers in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I get the point (x,y) at which the marker is plotted while plotting custom marker.

I don't want the x and y in pixels but the series point that are shown in tooltip 
[image]

I want to get this point is custom symbol that I am rendering .Please suggest me some workaround

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.pointer = function (x, y, w, h) {
        cr = 12;
        return ['M', x, y-h, 
                'C',x,y-h,x-cr,y,x,y+h, 
                     'M', x, y,
                'L',x+w,y+h,x,y+h,x,y,
                     'L',x+w,y+h,x+w,y-h,x,y-h,
                     'M', x+w, y-h, 
                'C',x+w,y-h,x+w+cr,y,x+w,y+h, 
                'z'];


    };
    if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
        Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.pointer = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.pointer;
    }
```

Comment: `I want to get this point is custom symbol that I am rendering.` - could you explain? If you want to get x/yValue in your symbol renderer, then it's not possible. Symbol renderer is expected to draw some shape according to passed arguments.

Comment: @PawełFus .What I want to achieve is to write the value of point on y axis in the marker . Is this possible anyhow  ?

Comment: Sure, just enable dataLabels, [see docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels).